# How to find where an element will be inserted into a std::map without actually inserting it

Tags: c++, dictionary, stdmap, std

Is there a way to easily find an iterator where an element would be inserted into a `std::map`, without actually inserting the element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best you can do is use:

**[std::map::upper_bound()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/upper_bound/)** or
**[std::map::lower_bound()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/lower_bound/)**
to get the iterator positions where key is greater than or greater than or equal to a specific key value.

Comment: It's worth noting that if you pass the result of `lower_bound` to `insert` as a hint, you get constant-time performance of the latter.